# Include json-c in C project

Tags: c, json, nfc, json-c

I have a `libnfc` project that I compile with `make-install` and run my file with `./xxx` 
Now I want to use `json-c` in `xxx.c` but a simple `"#include <json/json.h>"` does not work. How can I access the json-c methods from xxx.c?

Thanks for your answers,

Sophie

Comment: What error do you get?  If it is "undefined reference to..." you need to link to the library as well as including its header.  If you post sample code plus build command and the error you get, someone will probably explain the exact changes you need

Comment: Please show us the relevant parts of your code, or at least the exact error message you're getting

Comment: Edit:
my codes looks as followed:

xxx.c:
...
#include <json-c-0.9/json.h>
...
char * string = ("{\"test\" : \"test test\"}");
json_object * jobj = json_tokener_parse(string);
...

the following error shows up when doing make install:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_json_tokener_parse", referenced from:
      _nfcforum_tag4_io in nfc-emulate-forum-tag4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

json.h exists in the subdir. what do you mean with "link to the library"?

Thanks for your fast answers so far,

Sophie

Answer (score 3):

On linux you need add something like

-I/usr/include/json-c -L/usr/lib -ljson-c

to your compile command.

Answer (score -1):

If u installed json-c as

```
/usr/local/include/json
```

Then use

```
gcc -ljson
```

If u installed as below path

```
/usr/local/include/json-c
```

then use
gcc -ljson-c